# How do you publish so it works on other computers?

Tags: xna-4.0

how do i publish my game so i can use it on other computers? When i tried publishing it, it worked on my computer ( the application) but not on another computer.

Comment: A little more detail would help. How did you publish it? When you say it didn't work, what do you mean? Did it crash, or not run at all? Was there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Click *create* in VS.
Select *Publish Yourprojectname*
Follow the steps in the helper
After the creation is finished, a folder is opening. Don't launch the setup but the *.application* file which ic checking if the XNA-Framework is installed and, if not, automatically lanch setup.exe.

[I translated these steps form German to English so if a button is namend a bit diferent you now know why]

Comment: Sorry but the set up doesn't work for some reason and people tell me i have to download visual studios again to get the right files, it works on computers with visual studios on so it know it works. I dont want to have to download visual studios again on every computer

Comment: And you have given them all the files in the folder of the setup?

Comment: Yeah i have, i even checked in the content folder